# How to detect if rails is at the root url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

What I want is seems simple.

In my application helper i setup this

```
module ApplicationHelper

def isroot
if root_url 
@container = "mainbox"
else
@container = "maincontainerbox"
end
end
end
```

in my application layout i have this

```
 <div id="<%= isroot %>">
```

How do I find out if my application is at the homepage.  if not do something else.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

To test if you are at the site root:

```
current_page?('/')
```

or, if you defined `map.root` in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
current_page?(root_url)
```