# trying to render a partial based on whether it's the home page "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, conditional-statements, partial

I thought this bit of **code** might work, but...it didn't Any ideas?

```
<% if "/"? %>
  <%= render 'layouts/homeHeader' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to use code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1924663) you can do this:

```
<% if current_page?(root_url) %>
  <%= render 'layouts/homeHeader' %> 
<% else %> 
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %> 
<% end %>
```