# Ruby / Rails - Hide Navbar & Footer on Root Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, navbar

I would like to hide the navbar and footer on the root page only. I am using RoR. I currently have my navbar in my application file to prevent repetitiveness. I assume a filter on my application controller?

Comment: [How to detect if rails is at the root url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924620/how-to-detect-if-rails-is-at-the-root-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in view `application.html.erb` :

```
<% unless controller.controller_name == "your_root_controller" && controller.action_name == "your_action" %>
  <nav> 
       #something
  </nav>
<% end %>
```

or even you can make in helper something method like this:

```
def root? 
 controller.controller_name == "your_root_controller" && controller.action_name == "your_action"
end
```

and next in view `application.html.erb`:

```
if root?
  #something html
end
```

or you can also use `current_page?`method, and in this way:

in view `application.html.erb`

```
if current_page?(root_path)
  # your html
end
```

Comment: The multiple solutions are appreciated. Would you recommend a specific one for production use?

Comment: if only for root i recommend for you last solution with `current_page?` method