# Efficient conditional statement to hide certain layout elements (navbar/footer) on root

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, conditional-statements

*I posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355210/ruby-rails-hide-navbar-footer-on-root-page). It may seem duplicated but this question is different in that I specifically want a conditional statement to remove a portion of the layout (not the entire file)*

I have tried:

```
if current_page?(root_path)
  # your html
end
```

application.html.erb (updated version below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<!--Google Fonts-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand|Raleway:600"    rel="stylesheet">

<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body>

<!--Navbar/Footer-->
 <% if current_page?(root_path) %>
   #NAVBAR
   #FOOTER
 <% end %>**

<!--Javascript-->
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
 });
</script>

<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">      </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Updated application.html.erb

```
<% if current_page?(root_path) %>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="content">
    <%= yield %>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
<% else %>  
 <body>
  <!--Header-->
  <%= render 'shared/header' %>
  <!--Content-->
  <div class="container">
   <div class="content">
    <%= yield %>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!--Footer-->
   <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
  </body>
<% end %>
```

Add navbar to **app/views/shared/header.html.erb**

Add footer to **app/views/shared/footer.html.erb**

Comment: What have you tried? (ie what have you learned from the answer given to your other question)? :)

Comment: Show your application.html.erb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i can't see your application.html.erb ill give an example:

Inside your `application.html.erb` make 2 body's and make one show on the root page and the other one on all other pages like this:

```
<% if current_page?(root_path) %>
    <body>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
<% else %>  
    <body>
    <%= render 'shared/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
       <%= yield %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
    </body>
<% end %>
```

This is assuming that you have your footer and header as partials inside your `app/views/shared` folder

Comment: Applying your assumption, I created a shared folder in my views. I separated the header & footer into files named: header.html.erb & footer.html.erb. I then applied your solution to my application.html.erb file. I am now receiving the following error: ActionView::MissingTemplate in Devise::Sessions#new. Any further guidance that you care to share?

Comment: This will work fine, but it's a bummer to duplicate so much! Probably better to have two `if`s, one around each `render`.  About the missing template error - the file names for partials need to start with an underscore, like "_header.html.erb" and "_footer.html.erb".

Comment: The problem has been resolved utilizing luissimo's solution but with @gmcnaughton's revisions. I did not include anything (literally blank) between the if & else but included the render partials between else & end.

Comment: Nice! You can also make it shorter by using `<% unless ... %>` instead of `if` then no empty `else` clause needed!